# diff behaviour between perl 5.8.8 and 5.10.1

Tags: perl

I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$LOGFILE = "Soccer.txt";
open(LOGFILE) or die("Could not open log file.");
foreach $line (<LOGFILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    ($hour, $match, $idh, $back1, $lay1, $idd, $backx, $layx, $ida, $back2, $lay2) = split(/\s*,\s*/,$line);
    $match =~ s/^(\d{2}):(\d{2}) //g; #/ # fix highlighting
    ($hteam,$ateam) = split(/\s*§\s*/,$match,2);
    $hteam = get_name($hteam);
    $ateam = get_name($ateam);
    $match = "$hteam - $ateam";

    $foo=qq($hour "$match" $idh $back1 $lay1 $idd $backx $layx $ida $back2 $lay2 \n) ;
    print $foo;
}
sub get_name {
# Return the full name for the team, if it exists, otherwise return the original
    my %alias = (
        "Aalen" => "Vfr Aalen",
        "Accrington" => "Accrington Stanley",
        "Accrington St" => "Accrington Stanley",
        "Adelaide Utd" => "Adelaide United Fc"
    );
    return $alias{$_[0]} // $_[0];
}
```

This scrpit works perfect in my system:

```
perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Now I would like run it in a different system:

```
perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Search pattern not terminated at ./scriptbd.robot.pl line 458.
```

Why am I getting an error?

Comment: There's isn't 458 lines in the program you posted. :)

Comment: What happens if you replace '§' with a standard ASCII character?

Comment: You really should begin your scripts with `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return $alias{$_[0]} // $_[0];
```

The [`//` operator was added in 5.10](http://p3rl.org/perl5100delta#Defined-or-operator). To make it work on earlier Perls, rewrite it:

```
return (defined $alias{$_[0]}) ? $alias{$_[0]} : $_[0];
```

Comment: If all hash values evaluate to false, it could be written smaller using logical-or (`||`). But there's not much point, since we are only considering how to fix a problem using a legacy Perl.